# Does mod_mono need xsp to work or to work better?

Tags: mono, apache2, mod-mono, xsp, apache2.2

I run an apache 2.2 web server to serve asp.net web applications with mod_mono. It works fine. But mono-xsp2 service running too..

Does mod_mono need xsp to work or to work better?

I am asking that because xsp-server start running automatically on boot time. And I couldn't be sure if it is needed or not.

Here is a screenshot of the process'
http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/839/capturetu.png

If you see something on the screenshot which is not good for me, Please let me know.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I have edited my question because it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`XSP` server just a development and testing environment. For production you have to use `Apache`.

A proof link, for example, [this](http://go-mono.com/forums/#nabble-td26856467).

Comment: Thanks. You are absolutely right. But my question was not just that. I have edited it to be more specific. Thank you for your answer...

Comment: Hi. No, mod_mono doesn't require xsp to be installed at all. This is independent modules. Both requires mono runtime and this is only one similarity.

Comment: Thank you! Also I recommend to join mono mailing lists at http://www.mono-project.com/Mailing_Lists - there you can receive the most professional answer to your questions. StackOverflow is also good enought

Comment: The link is broken, can you update the link to point to the mailing list archive instead of Nabble?

Comment: @knocte: hi, unfortunately I cannot. However you can try to start from [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono).